# Blog Image not Display in Home Page Big-commerce - Stencil

Tags: php, jquery, html, bigcommerce

This is the code I have for **Home.html**

```
<br/><br/>
{{#each blog.recent_posts}}
<br/><br/>
{{> components/blog/post post=this settings=../settings}}
<br/><br/>
{{/each}}
```

This is the code I have for **Post.html**

```
<br/>
<"header class="blog-header"><br/>
    <"/h2 class="blog-title"><br/>
    <"img src="{{getImage thumbnail 'blog_size'}}" alt="{{thumbnail.alt}}" title="{{thumbnail.alt}}">
        <br/>
        <a href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a><br/>
    </h2>
    <br/>
    <p class="blog-date">{{#if post.author}}{{lang 'blog.posted_by' name=post.author}} on {{/if}}{{post.date_published}}</p><br/>
</header>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stencil, you need to remove post. since the global blog.recent_posts structure if different than blog.posts and for some reason.

```
{{#each blog.recent_posts}}
        {{#if thumbnail}}
            <figure class="blog-thumbnail">
                <a href="{{url}}">
                    <img src="{{getImage thumbnail 'blog_size'}}" alt="{{thumbnail.alt}}" title="{{thumbnail.alt}}">
                </a>
            </figure>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: In home page 
     {{#each blog.recent_posts}}
       {{> components/blog/homepost post=this settings=../settings}}
    {{/each}}

Comment: Yes open your home.html from stencil editing files options and then paste the above code in your HTML sections where you would like to show post image, you can similarly be added date title for your blogs.

Comment: How you upload a image of blog first let me know i think i am wrong on this way

Comment: admin end :   http://prntscr.com/fbexgt      http://prntscr.com/fbexo2   http://prntscr.com/fbextv  then save it

Comment: Yes before  I already do this same thing but still not display

Comment: I will test it on my end

Comment: Check your mail i sending two file my home.html and post.html

Comment: ok so i have checked you did litle bit code wrong  first open your home.html

Comment: find this line {{> components/blog/homepost post=this settings=../settings}}  {{thumbnail.alt}}  replace it with   <figure class="blog-thumbnail">
                <a href="{{url}}">
                    <img src="{{getImage thumbnail 'blog_size'}}" alt="{{thumbnail.alt}}" title="{{thumbnail.alt}}">
                </a>
            </figure>

Comment: check your email

Comment: OMG Really its work ... :) You are awesome dude ... Thank you so much.

You made my day ... finally yarrr thank you

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some syntactical issues with your markup.

```
{{#each blog.recent_posts}}

    {{> components/blog/post post=this settings=../settings}}

{{/each}}
```

Post.html

```
<header class="blog-header">
    <h2 class="blog-title">
        {{post.title}}
    </h2>
    <img src="{{getImage thumbnail 'blog_size'}}" alt="{{thumbnail.alt}}" title="{{thumbnail.alt}}"> 

    {{#if post.author}}
        {{lang 'blog.posted_by' name=post.author}} on 
    {{/if}}

    {{post.date_published}}
</header>
```

Comment: Are you able to describe your issue in more detail? 
Are you seeing the `blog-title`? or is the image displaying strangely?

Comment: Check this two image 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx15kkpY6kksX21pZ2xwY3lRVTQ

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx15kkpY6kksWWRZSzA3RFE4elk

I want to display blog image in home page

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but there may be an issue with the parameters you're passing into `getImage`.
Can you please verify that your "thumbnail" is a valid image and "blog_size" is a valid size?

Refer to the Stencil helper docs: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#image